# Appending dropdown selection to url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append the dropdown selection to the url.

This selection part

```
    <div class="search2">
                <span>Adults</span><select id="adult" class="dropdown-select" name="selectdropdown">
                <option value="0">-</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>

</select>
</div>
```

Then the call sign

```
var Adult = $("#adult");
```

Final the append to url sign

```
url = url + "RedirectFromOutSide.aspx?arrivaldate=" + stringdata($("#StartDate").datepicker('getDate')) + "&departuredate=" + stringdata($("#EndDate").datepicker('getDate')) + "&hotelid=" + HotelID + "&Type=" + type + "&lang=" + Culture + "&adults=" + Adult;
```

But as the result comes `&adults=object%...` instead of `&adults=1` or `2` or `3` or `4`.

Comment: `var Adult = $("#adult").val();`?

Comment: VDWWD the result is 0 but

Comment: @KennethCamilleri What do you expect to pass if the selected option is `-` (with value `0`)? Would you like to use the text or value? Or do you want to omit the `&adults=` query parameter if `0` is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the value:

```
$( "#adult").val();
```

However, if you want to get the selected text from drop-down:

```
$( "#adult option:selected" ).text();
```

Refer to this post:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value of adult.

Try this code:

```
var Adult = $("#adult").val();
```

Comment: I added to URL the following $( "#adult option:selected" ).text(); and worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

I added it direct to URL like below

```
url = url + "RedirectFromOutSide.aspx?arrivaldate=" + stringdata($("#StartDate").datepicker('getDate')) + "&departuredate=" + stringdata($("#EndDate").datepicker('getDate')) + "&hotelid=" + HotelID + "&Type=" + type + "&lang=" + Culture + "&adults=" + $( "#adult option:selected" ).text();
```